# SQL : Extract last 12 months of data from SQL server when period is in the format of yyyymm

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, time

I have a SQL server table that looks like this

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| 202010 | A |
| 202011 | B |
| 202012 | C |
| 202101 | D |
| 202102 | E |
| 202103 | F |
| 202104 | G |
| 202105 | H |
| 202106 | I |
| 202107 | J |
| 202108 | K |
| 202109 | L |
| 202110 | M |
| 202111 | N |

The monthid is a column in the format of yyyymm with integer datatype.

I need to extract the last 12 months of data.

Can someone please suggest how I can do it

Comment: you can use implicit conversion with convert `where yyyymm > CONVERT(char(6),DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE()),112)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE [A header] >= YEAR(DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())) * 100 + MONTH(DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE()))
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2a5756418e623721de4162e0ab2b2cfc)

This is made worse by the fact you are storing dates as integers. Instead you should store the last day of the month **as a `date` type**, then you can do

```
WHERE [A header] >= DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I pass a parameter of yearmonth to SQL query. For example if I pass 202010 it should show 202010-201910

Comment: Change `GETDATE()` for your parameter. Pass in a parameter of `date` type, not `int`

Answer (score 0):

Covert your data to a `Pandas DataFrame`. You can check how to do [here](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-convert-an-sql-query-result-to-a-pandas-dataframe-in-python).

```py
# Convert date column to datetime
df['A header'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A header'], format='%Y%m')

# Sort and select last 12 months
df.sort_values(by='A header',ascending=True).set_index("A header").last("12M").reset_index()
```

```sh
| A header            | Another header   |
|:--------------------|:-----------------|
| 2020-12-01 00:00:00 | C                |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | D                |
| 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | E                |
| 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | F                |
| 2021-04-01 00:00:00 | G                |
| 2021-05-01 00:00:00 | H                |
| 2021-06-01 00:00:00 | I                |
| 2021-07-01 00:00:00 | J                |
| 2021-08-01 00:00:00 | K                |
| 2021-09-01 00:00:00 | L                |
| 2021-10-01 00:00:00 | M                |
| 2021-11-01 00:00:00 | N                |
```

Comment: I need o extract it from a SQL server table.
I am forming a SQL query and then executing it using python

Comment: Your tag was Pandas..?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert that column into `datetime` then just use it in the query, like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT *, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, A) + '01') MethodIdDateTime FROM Sample
 ) e
 WHERE 
   MethodIdDateTime >= DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE())
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5b31b/8)

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from [TableName]
where convert(date,left(A header,4)+'- 
'+right(A header,2)+'-01')>DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())
Order by convert(date,left(A header,4)+'-'+right(A header,2)+'-01') desc
```

Comment: This will only retrieve only 12 records. What if there was multiple records

Answer (score 0):

I modified @Charlieface query only,

```
CREATE TABLE #YourTable (
  "A header" INTEGER,
  "Another header" VARCHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO #YourTable
  ("A header", "Another header")
VALUES
  ('202010', 'A'),
  ('202011', 'B'),
  ('202012', 'C'),
  ('202101', 'D'),
  ('202102', 'E'),
  ('202103', 'F'),
  ('202104', 'G'),
  ('202105', 'H'),
  ('202106', 'I'),
  ('202107', 'J'),
  ('202108', 'K'),
  ('202109', 'L'),
  ('202110', 'M'),
  ('202111', 'N');

  declare  @To int =202012
  declare @From int = format(dateadd(month,-12, cast(concat(@To,'01') as date)),'yyyyMM')
  --select @From
  SELECT *
FROM #YourTable
WHERE ([A header] >= @From and [A header]<=@To)
drop table #YourTable
```